# Unable to compile and install web karma using maven

Tags: maven, karma-runner

I have installed maven successfully and when i check for the Maven version it displays the below information:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:4
7-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

I have downloaded the Zip folder for Karma and followed the instructions that are mentioned for karma tool installation from the site https://github.com/usc-isi-i2/Web-Karma/wiki/Installation%3A-Source-Code#system-requirements

I have extracted the sip folder to a directory and opened a shell (command prompt) and navigated to the directory where I extracted Karma.On the shell prompt typed mvn clean install

I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project karma-util: Fatal error compiling: direct
ory not found: C:\Program Files\Web-Karma-master\karma-util\target\classes -> [H
elp 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :karma-util
```

I am not sure where am I wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How have you started to build?

Comment: I have extracted it to a directory and opened a shell (command prompt) and navigated to the directory where I extracted Karma.On the shell prompt typed mvn clean install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously I was trying in Program Files folder in C drive so I could not install. I changed the folder I am able to install it now.